# PL-SQL - Using Split fuction and get dataType error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this function that separates the primary keys by commas and does the search, but when passing the keys to the function I'm getting the following error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got RDVE.SPLIT_TBL
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

Function:

```
create or replace type split_tbl as table of varchar2(32767);

create or replace function split2(

  list in varchar2,
  delimiter in varchar2 default ','

) 

return split_tbl as
  splitted split_tbl := split_tbl();
  i pls_integer := 0;
  list_ varchar2(32767) := list;

begin
  loop
    i := instr(list_, delimiter);
    if i > 0 then
      splitted.extend(1);
      splitted(splitted.last) := substr(list_, 1, i - 1);
      list_ := substr(list_, i + length(delimiter));
    else
      splitted.extend(1);
      splitted(splitted.last) := list_;
      return splitted;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Calling the function and performing select:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM INFO_APONTAMENT info
  WHERE  info.Boat_Id = split2(:id)
  ORDER BY info.Date DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

already tried to change the types to CHAR, but it did not solve

Comment: What do you pass as a parameter (:id)? What result do you expect from the split2 function (based on that input)?

Comment: unless info.boat_id is of type split_tbl, how do you expect the where clause to figure out if it equals split2(:id). Try doing a simple SELECT split2(:1d) from dual to make sure the function works as the first step would be my suggestion.

Comment: @Littlefoot My idea is to look up the records of the keys that were separated in the SPLIT_TBL table, so I did a search by passing the keys that will be entered by the user, but I may have to save these records in another table.

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it, it seems that this might do the job:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM INFO_APONTAMENT info
  WHERE  info.Boat_Id in (select * from table(split2(:id)))    --> this
  ORDER BY info.Date DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

I created your function in my database and used it on Scott's EMP table, so - if that's what you wanted it to do, see if it helps.

```
SQL> select deptno, ename
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno in (select * from table(split2('10,20')));

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 MILLER
        10 KING
        10 CLARK
        20 FORD
        20 ADAMS
        20 SCOTT
        20 JONES
        20 SMITH

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MEMBER OF` operator:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   INFO_APONTAMENT info
WHERE  info.Boat_Id MEMBER OF split2('1,2,3,123')
ORDER BY info."Date" DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

However, that will only return a single row.

If you want the latest row for each `boat_id` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT info.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY boat_id ORDER BY "Date" DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   INFO_APONTAMENT info
  WHERE  info.Boat_Id MEMBER OF split2('1,2,3,123')
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2324a3c158237333c0d57504f82eca3e)